# Check if all values are equal in a list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
Class order {
Guid Id;
int qty;
}
```

Using LINQ expression, how can I verify if the `qty` is the same for all orders in a list?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
bool allEqual = orders.GroupBy(o => o.qty).Count() == 1;
```

or, little bit more efficient but less readable:

```
bool allEqual = !orders.GroupBy(o => o.qty).Skip(1).Any();
```

or, definitely more efficient using [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx):

```
int firstQty = orders.First().qty;  // fyi: throws an exception on an empty sequence
bool allEqual = orders.All(o => o.qty == firstQty);
```

Comment: If you move the `orders.First().qty` inside the lambda, you won't get an exception for empty sequences (because the lambda won't be invoked if the sequence is empty) - at the cost of recalculating the value each time the lambda is invoked.

Comment: @sepp2k: hence i would simply use  `if(orders.Any()){}` at the beginning. That's clear and efficient.

Comment: You could improve the efficiency of the GroupBy version slightly by doing  `var allEqual = !orders.GroupBy(o => o.qty).Skip(1).Any()`. Now if you have many quantities it only checks to see if a 2nd exists instead of counting all the groups (however the `.All(` version is still better).

Answer (score 3):

I would add an extension method, if only to improve readability.

```
public static bool AllEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var value = enumerator.Current;

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (!comparer.Equals(enumerator.Current, value))
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Calling it:

```
var qtyEqual = orders.Select(order => order.qty).AllEqual();
```